# Why isn't nc -vv -l -n -p 8080 working?

Tags: netcat, listener

I can't get the command working, it should listen to 8080

I am out of idea's with this, any support on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **-p** option is used for specifying source port **nc** should use in connect mode and can't be used together with **-l** option which specifies that **nc** should run in listen mode. So you need to run

```
nc -v -l -n 8080
```

For explanation of other options, please check [nc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc).